# get xml element using php

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML page called (www.example.com/name.xml)
it contains the bellow elements :

```
<xml>
    <names>
        <name id='6' >Name 1 </name>
        <name id='7'>Name 2</name>
        <name id='8'>Name 3</name>
    </names>
</xml>
```

and here is my PHP script :

```
<?php
$id='6';
$url = "www.example.come/name.xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$position ="$xml->name id='$id' ";
?>
```

So how can I get it ?

Comment: what you want exactly,
just getting xml file data and showing on browser?

Comment: yes , this is what i want

Comment: Then you can go with file_get_content and show it.

Comment: You do not understand me well , but what i meant is that i want to get the element with the id (6) for example but when i try to generate it in the browser i don't get anything .Also , when i tried this code for an element with ID , it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `xpath` for this:

```
$id='6';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$position = (string)$xml->xpath("//name[@id='$id']")[0];
echo $position;
```

Output:

```
Name 1
```

This uses `xpath` to get the text from the `<name>` where `id` is 6. Then it casts the `SimpleXMLElement` to `(string)`, thus providing the output.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided data, you could do it like this:

```
$id='6';

foreach($xml->names->name as $name) {
    if ((string)$name->attributes()->id === $id) {
        // here $name will be the element for which the attribute id='6'
        var_dump($name);
    }
}
```

Will result in:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Name 1 "
}
```

`$name` is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) and the value you are looking for is in the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

Comment: Thank you , it works , but it don't get the element that contains the id 6 .

Comment: The element that contains the id 6 is the `$name` variable.